# How do I properly extend the AS3 Point class?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, extend

I come to need a bit more info from my points, so I thought I'd add a previousX, previousY so that I can get a deltaX and deltaY. Now, this works fine if I make a simple self-contained class.

I think, however, that I'd like to extend the flash.geom.Point class to benefit from the other functions and calculations it offers.

So I extended Point and modified the x and y setters as I needed. When I compile, I get an error that these setters are not marked for override when they should be. So I override, but then I get an error that says these do not override any function.

Any clue where I screwed up?

Here is the class:

```
package net.jansensan.geom
{
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * @author Mat Janson Blanchet
     */
    public class UpdatablePoint extends Point
    {
        private var _previousX : Number = 0;
        private var _previousY : Number = 0;
        private var _deltaX    : Number = 0;
        private var _deltaY    : Number = 0;

        // ********************************************************************
        //                         [ PUBLIC METHODS ]
        // ********************************************************************

        public function UpdatablePoint(x:Number=0, y:Number=0)
        {
            super(x, y);
        }

        override public function toString():String
        {
            return "(x=" + super.x + ", y=" + super.y + ", previousX=" +
                _previousX + ", previousY=" + _previousY + ", deltaX=" +
                _deltaX + ", deltaY=" + _deltaY + ")";
        }

        // ********************************************************************
        //                        [ GETTERS / SETTERS ]
        // ********************************************************************

        override public function set x(x:Number):void
        {
            _previousX = super.x;
            super.x = x;
            _deltaX = super.x - _previousX;
        }

        override public function set y(y:Number):void
        {
            _previousY = super.y;
            super.y = y;
            _deltaY = super.y - _previousY;
        }

        public function get previousX():Number
        {
            return _previousX;
        }

        public function get previousY():Number
        {
            return _previousY;
        }

        public function get deltaX():Number
        {
            return _deltaX;
        }

        public function get deltaY():Number
        {
            return _deltaY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the exact text of the errors in both cases? With and without the `override` statements. You might be overriding an extra function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Point` class isn't implemented using get/set-methods, rather it contains only public variables: `public var x : Number` and `public var y : Number`. See the documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#x).

Since you cannot override any public getters or setters you can't detect when anyone using your class is writing to these variables. What you can do is remove the `extends Point` and add a `Point` instance variable to your UpdatablePoint. Then change your getters and setters for x/y from super.[x/y] to myPointInstance.[x/y].

If you need to expose more functionality from the Point class, you could easily just wrap it. I.e. Say you want to use the 'equals'-method from Point, just create a copy of that method signature and make it's body contain: `return myPointInstance.equals(p);`

Answer (score 2):

Point does not have `public function set x` or `public function set y`.

So you can't override them as they don't exist. Point is very low-level, my guess would be that Adobe didn't add these functions to avoid the increase in overload.